# slanting of non-square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for an operation to ''slant'' a (not necessarily square) matrix.

I want this:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & l
\end{bmatrix}
$
to become: 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & a & b & c & d \\ 0 & e & f & g & h & 0\\ i & j & k & l & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

If the original matrix has `r` rows and `c` columns, the new should have `r` rows and `r+c-1` columns.

I'm sure I could do it by iterating, but I'd prefer some sort of translation (shearing/skewing etc.).

Any ideas?